# How can an array of a data type with the size [1] suddenly be bigger than the datatype itself in Java

Tags: java, arrays, types

today I have been experimenting with memory in java. Specifically, I was deserializing objects into binary data and reserializing them. Something caught my eye and that is that for example an array of bytes with the size 1 takes up less binary data than defining a byte. Here's what I mean:

I defined a single byte in java and printed out the binary data of the byte:

```
byte size: 75bytes
101011001110110100000000000001010111001101110010000000000000111001101010011000010111011001100001001011100110110001100001011011100110011100101110010000100111100101110100011001011001110001001110011000001000010011101110010100001111010100011100000000100000000000000001010000100000000000000101011101100110000101101100011101010110010101111000011100100000000000010000011010100110000101110110011000010010111001101100011000010110111001100111001011100100111001110101011011010110001001100101011100101000011010101100100101010001110100001011100101001110000010001011000000100000000000000000011110000111000000000001
```

and here's a byte[1] array

```
byte[] size: 28bytes
10101100111011010000000000000101011101010111001000000000000000100101101101000010101011001111001100010111111110000000011000001000010101001110000000000010000000000000000001111000011100000000000000000000000000000000000100000001
```

But if I print out the size of byte[0] (byte at location 0 in the array) it suddenly grows back to 75bytes:

```
size of byte[0] in byte array:
101011001110110100000000000001010111001101110010000000000000111001101010011000010111011001100001001011100110110001100001011011100110011100101110010000100111100101110100011001011001110001001110011000001000010011101110010100001111010100011100000000100000000000000001010000100000000000000101011101100110000101101100011101010110010101111000011100100000000000010000011010100110000101110110011000010010111001101100011000010110111001100111001011100100111001110101011011010110001001100101011100101000011010101100100101010001110100001011100101001110000010001011000000100000000000000000011110000111000000000001
```

And yes, it's the full object and not metadata or something because using this binary i can reconstruct the object to it's original state so the values are stored inside the binary data. Here's the code I used to find out the size of the data:

```java
public class MemoryFunctions {
    static int sizeOf(Object input) {
        int size = 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream checker = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream byteArray = new ObjectOutputStream(checker);
            byteArray.writeObject(input);
            byteArray.flush();
            byte sizeDetector[]  = checker.toByteArray();
            size = sizeDetector.length;
            int amountOfBytes = 0;
            for (byte b:
                 sizeDetector) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
                amountOfBytes +=1;
            }
            System.out.println("real size in byte " + amountOfBytes);
            System.out.println();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason, that a byte array takes up less space than the byte itself? I need to heavily optimize a program. Using this information, would it be a better idea to have the values of a class that I want to deserialize into binary data in array form or are there any benefits of using "the full value"? Also, I am kind of confused with this information because as far as I know, byte and byte[] are primitive datatypes so they don't get called by reference but are stored as binary in memory "as is". What I also found out that getting the size of value 0 in the smaller array suddenly generates me a new int because it's size is again 75 bytes. Does this mean that values are generated another time when you call an index of an array?

It'd be nice if any of you had more information about this topic and could answer my questions.

Comment: Note that `ObjectOutputStream` tells you nothing about the size of the object _in memory,_ just the size of the object when serialized, _with_ all the expense of any headers or trailing data added by the `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java `byte` is a primitive type passed by-value, but *all* arrays are effectively objects and by-reference, including `byte[]`.

If you pass a `byte[1]` to your `sizeOf` it passes the array, because all object types are subclasses of and compatible with the parameter `Object input`, and `sizeOf` serializes the array.

If you try to pass a primitive `byte` it doesn't work, because no primitive type is a reference type so it cannot be compatible with `java.lang.Object` or any other object type. Instead the `byte` is ['boxed'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) to an an object of the language-defined class `java.lang.Byte` (note different spelling) -- and `sizeOf` serializes *that object*. This is often called *auto-boxing* (and auto-unboxing for the reverse) because the compiler does these conversions without you writing them in the source code. The boxed object is actually about the same size in memory as the array (and both are significantly larger than the primitive), but as commented by https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman the *serialization* of the `java.lang.Byte` object is more complicated and longer than the *serialization* of the `byte[1]` array.